# Converting the date to string, instead of Object

Tags: javascript, html

The issue is that the date is outputted as [object Object]. How do we parse it to string or does this have to be done differently?

```
var completelist = document.getElementById("thelist");
var currentTime = new Date();
var items= [];

todoButton.onclick=function addelement() {
  var userTodoInput = document.getElementById("todoInput"); 
  let node = document.createElement("LI");
  node.innerHTML = userTodoInput.value;
  completelist.appendChild(node);
  items.push({userTodoInput,currentTime});
  for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
    var id = items[0];
            
    document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML += "<div  class='todo' style='max-width:300px; margin:0 auto;' ><p id='t-list'> You have added this to the list of actions: " + userTodoInput.value + " . The date of the to-do creation is : "+id+"</p></br></div>";

  }    
}
```

Comment: The `Date` is not output as `"[object Object]"`; the object `{ userTodoInput, currentTime }` is. What is the expected stringification for it? If you expect just the date, then get the date directly: `items[0].currentTime` or `id.currentTime`.

Comment: um, `var id = items[0];` is wrong since each item in the output would be the first item in the array and you are referencing an object and not the `currentTime` key inside of that object.

Answer (score 0):

To convert Object to String, simply just use JSON.stringify()

Answer (score -1):

It can be done using

```
 items.push({
     userInput: userTodoInput,
     time: currentTime
 });
```

After pushing
Accesing the innerHTML as

```
 document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML += "<div>" + items[0].time + "</div>"
```

Comment: What is incorrect about the way the object is pushed to array? The values certainly are attainable. Do some research into how destructuring works

Comment: agree, edited the answer, what I meant to say was with keys, it is easier. thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Easier is subjective and is very different from "incorrect"